# Days between two dates in Javascript or Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, count

I want some calculation with Javascript or jquery. actually I have two inputs with date picker. I want when I selected dates in both field a new field value should appear which will have the total number of days for selected date. For example: 
I select in input one : 2012-01-01
and
I select in input two: 2013-01-01
then in field three value should be = 365 Days

Hope you understand. 
I know how to count days between two dates:

```
$days = (strtotime($termi_date) - strtotime($str_date)) / (60 * 60 * 24);
echo $days;
```

Comment: Do you want help to convert that PHP code into JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var from_date = $("#from_input").datepicker('getDate'),
    to_date   = $("#to_input").datepicker('getDate');

var diff_in_milliseconds = to_date.getTime() - from_date.getTime();
```

or simply

```
diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VhBA8/1/)**

Comment: What should I print where i want to print the days count result ? and how ? please tell me

Comment: There is a demo right ,all the code is there,along with date pickers.

Comment: Thank you so much its really what I want.. You are great